# The number of ways in which a team containing atleast one woman is formed

Tags: combinatorics

From a group of 8 men and 4 women a team of 5 including atleast 1 woman is to be formed.Find the number of ways in which this team can be formed.

What i've done:
No of ways to select one woman is 4 **AND** No. of ways to select remaining 4 members is C(11,4) since there are totally 11 people left now and there is no further restriction/condition for their selection
∴ Total ways to select team= 4*C(11,4)=1320
But the answer given in my textbook is 736
Can someone please explain what is wrong in my  approach and whats the correct way to do this?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are over counting...every team with more than one woman gets counted repeatedly.

Comment: Just count all possible 5-teams minus 5-teams with no woman.

Comment: Taking your proposed solution to the extreme, suppose you have two men and zero women and you wish to count the number of groups of two you can make with at least one man.  According to your solution, you would have an answer of two, but there is only one way to pick two people from two total.

Comment: A team with at least one woman is not a team that is all men.  It is easy to find the number of ways to select an all male team.  What have you done. you have not distinguished between the possibility that the "mandatory" woman might not also be selected with the "general draft."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve counted any team with more than one woman more than once. For instance, consider a team with all four women and one of the men, say $W_1,W_2,W_3,W_4$, and $M$: you’ve counted this once with $W_1$ as the woman initially chosen, once with $W_2$ as the woman initially chosen, and so on, so you’ve counted it $4$ times.

The easy approach is to count the teams that contain **no** woman and subtract that from the number of possible teams:

$$\binom{12}5-\binom85=792-56=736\;.$$